# PowerShell: Copy-GPO failing with HRESULT: 0x8007000D

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

While trying to run the `Copy-GPO` cmdlet to copy a Group Policy Object using a predefined *Migration Table* I am receiving this exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007000D): The data is invalid. (Exception from
HRESULT: 0x8007000D)
   at Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPMResultClass.OverallStatus()
   at Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Gpo.CopyTo(GPDomain targetDomain, String newDisplayName, Boolean copyAcl, GPMigrationTable
migrationTable, GPStatusMessageCollection& statusMessages)
   at Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.CopyGpoCommand.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
At C:\Users\djedig\Documents\OUCopy.ps1:335 char:2
+     NewGPOsFromTemplate "OU=$sSubDomain,OU=$sDivision,$sBaseRessourcenDN" $sTmplBas ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,NewGPOsFromTemplate
```

[This blog article](http://bittangents.com/2010/04/20/powershell-import-gpo-the-data-is-invalid-fixed/) suggests it would be due to unresolvable destination account data within the migration table but I seem unable to figure out the "correct" format of the migtable data. Indeed the GPO copies just fine when running `Copy-GPO` without the `-MigrationTable` parameter.

My command is:

```
Copy-GPO -SourceName $sTemplateGPOName -TargetName $sNewGPOName -MigrationTable $sMigrationTableFile
```

and the migration table contains a handful entries of these two types:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MigrationTable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/GroupPolicy/GPOOperations/MigrationTable">
  <Mapping>
    <Type>LocalGroup</Type>
    <Source>Template-allow-logon@ad.syneticon.net</Source>
    <Destination>RA-K17-DE-allow-logon@ad.syneticon.net</Destination>
  </Mapping>
[...]
  <Mapping>
    <Type>Unknown</Type>
    <Source>Administrators</Source>
    <DestinationSameAsSource />
  </Mapping>
</MigrationTable>
```

The `RA-K17-DE-allow-logon` security group *is* present as a local domain group and the sAMAccountName attribute is indeed set to the very same value.

What's puzzling me to no end is the fact that the [CopyGPO.wsf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814151%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_creating_a_copy_of_a_gpo) script from the GPMC scripting samples collection is perfectly able to create a GPO copy using the very same migration table like this:

```
cscript "//NoLogo" "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Group Policy\GPMC Sample Scripts\CopyGPO.wsf" $sTemplateGPOName $sNewGPOName "/MigrationTable:`"$sMigrationTableFile`"" | Out-Null
```

So what is going wrong here?

#### Edit:

The source GPO object just defines Restricted Groups and User Rights Assignments. All of the security principals used in those policies are included in the migtable file.

Comment: Is this still an issue? If so, what is/was in `$sMigrationTableFile`? The actual string I mean.

Comment: @MDMoore313 it is - kind of. I used a call to `cscript` and the `CopyGPO.WSF` script to work around the actual problem, but it is ugly as hell and has dependencies I would love to remove. The `$sMigrationTableFile` string contains the path to the migtable file - the same which is working with the `cscript` call above. It is something along the lines of `$sMigrationTableFile='C:\scripts\migrables\OUname.migtable'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue in more recent Powershell versions. I've tested basically the same syntax in Powershell 5 and 5.1 (after installing the appropriate WMF version on Server 2008 R2) and it works flawlessly. So this appears to be a bug in Powershell 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent all of 60 seconds looking at this, so this is a shot in the dark, but is this PowerShell object name spelled properly in your script?  `$sBaseRessourcenDN` The double 's' in *Resource* seems out of place, not to mention the random 'n'.

Comment: It is a localized variable name. It looks ugly in either language but that's what in fact has been defined and used throughout the script. Thanks for looking, though.